# How to rise double click event in disabled control?

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox and initially it is a disabled, because normally I don't want users can edit the value, but I would like to can enabled it in an easy way if the need to do it in some special cases.

For this, I would think to enabled the textbox if the user double clicks in the textbox, but how the control is disabled, the event is not rised.

I would like to know if there is some way to can rise events when the control is disabled or perhaps, and easy way to enabled the the control when is disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: you can overlay some transparent control on the disabled control. or as mentioned below, set it to read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should not "disable" it. Instead, set the textbox to "read only".

For this, set the `IsReadOnly` attribute to `true`.